# Java Regex: Text extraction into an array list

Tags: java, regex

I'm struggling with a simple regex, for which I can't seem to get right.

I have some text like so:

```
This comment is great **[@madeUpUser1](/madeUpUser1)** You said something similar did you mate? **[@madeUpUser2](/madeUpUser2)**
```

What I would like to end up with is an array list containing the usernames inbetween the parentheses i.e.:

```
0.madeUpUser1
1.madeUpUser2
```

And here is the code I have so far:

```
List<String> matches = Pattern.compile("\\((.+?)\\)")
        .matcher("This comment is great **[@madeUpUser1](/madeUpUser1)** You said something similar did you mate? **[@madeUpUser2](/madeUpUser2)**")
        .results()
        .map(MatchResult::group)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

However what I'm getting back is this:

```
0."(/madeUpUser1)"
1."(/madeUpUser2)"
```

Again, where I want:

```
0.madeUpUser1
1.madeUpUser2
```

i.e. without the parentheses and without the forwardslash

Can anyone shed any light on what I'm doing wrong with my regex please?

Comment: You can try [`(?<=\(\/)[^)]+(?=\))`](https://regex101.com/r/5bjDff/1).

Comment: I suggest adjusting the title of the question. So far, the accepted answer has no solution for "Text extraction into an array list", only a regex that can be used to do that. Maybe it should sound as "Extraction of string between parentheses excluding the first underscore", or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
(?<=\\(/)[^)]+(?=\\))
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dQbWMq/1)**

**Explanation**

- `(?<=\\(/)` - positive lookbehind to make sure that the current position is preceded by a `(/`
- `[^)]+` - matches 1 or more occurences(as many as possible) of any character that is not a `)`
- `(?=\\))` - positive lookahead to make sure that the current position is followed by a `)`

With the regex you are using, `\\((.+?)\\)`, the following happens:

- `\\(` - matches the opening parenthesis `(`
- `(.+?)` - matches any character(except a new line character) 1 or more times, as few as possible. This subpattern will keep on expanding the match until it reaches the `)`. That's why it is matching everything between the parenthesis(even the `/`)
- `\\)` - matches the closing parenthesis `)`

Comment: Wow thank you for the fast response, this works as expected. May I be a pain and ask can you explain it a bit for me so I can understand why it works? once again thank you very much!!

Comment: Performance-wise, Wiktor's answer is more efficient. I made use of lookarounds which are more expensive.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a capture group, and match the outer parenthesis/square brackets:

```
\(/([^\s()]+)\)
```

- `\(/` Match `(/`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^\s()]+` Match 1+ chars other than a whitespace char or `(` `)`
- `)` Close group 1
- `\)` Match `)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3GZ90M/1)

```
List<String> matches = Pattern.compile("\\(/([^\\s()]+)\\)")
    .matcher("This comment is great **[@madeUpUser1](/madeUpUser1)** You said something similar did you mate? **[@madeUpUser2](/madeUpUser2)**")
    .results()
    .map(m -> m.group(1))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

for (String s : matches)
    System.out.println(s);
```

Output

```
madeUpUser1
madeUpUser2
```

Or in the example, the string between the square brackets seems to be the same, so another option using the same code could be:

```
\[@([^\s\]\[]+)]
```

- `\[@` match `[@`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^\s\]\[]+` Match 1+ chars other than a whitespace char or `[` `]`
- `)` Close group 1
- `]` Match `]`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gt1LgO/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/O5Uixq)

Answer (score 1):

You can match `](/` and then *capture* any zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` till the next `)`, and collect Group 1 matches only:

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


class Test
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String text = "This comment is great **[@madeUpUser1](/madeUpUser1)** You said something similar did you mate? **[@madeUpUser2](/madeUpUser2)**";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("]\\(/([^()]*)\\)");
        List<String> results = p.matcher(text)
            .results()
            .map(mr -> mr.group(1))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        
        // Or, to get a string array:
        // String[] results = p.matcher(text).results().map(mr -> mr.group(1)).toArray(String[]::new);

        for (String x: results) {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
}
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/VUw5K5). Output:

```
madeUpUser1
madeUpUser2
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iXt7Wa/1). *Details*:

- `]\(/` - a `])/` string
- `([^()]*)` - Capturing group 1: any zero or more chars other than `)` and `(`
- `\)` -  a `)` char.